# Can I log to a non-default shell?

Tags: server, ssh, login, command-line, 8.04

I love fish. I have a nice Ubuntu 8.04 Server running some services. So I edited the /etc/passwd file, as I did in the past, to change my default shell from bash to fish. And ,yes, I made I typo (BTW: I know about chsh, I'm just that stupid and overconfident). Please, stop laughing.

As expected, now I can't login. Is it possible log in without restarting the server?. I know that I can restart the server in safe mode and solve the mess, but I'd like to avoid it.

Oh yeah, I have no other user with sudo rights in that server. Stop laughing again.

BTW, I made the mess using ssh, but I have easy physical access to the server, it's just a couple of rooms away.

Comment: I don't have a solution for you (suspect you do need to go and physically reboot the machine), but in future you should use `chsh` to change your login shells. It checks that you enter something which is valid (specified in `/etc/shells`)

Comment: I know, read the bit about being stupid and overconfident ;). Thank you anyway.

Comment: A simple NO, could be an answer too. Likely the correct one. BTW I had rebooted the server and corrected the mess by now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, no; you've locked yourself out. SSH won't let you log in if the shell is missing. Here's what the attempt looks like in `/var/log/auth.log`:

```
Dec 23 15:04:59 ubuntu sshd[5585]: User kees not allowed because shell /bin/fish does not exist
```

And on-console TTY login will always attempt to launch your configured shell. Without another user with `sudo` rights, you'll need to boot to single user mode to fix it. :(

Answer (score 1):

If you have a root password set, you can either log in as root on the machine itself (Either in X or on a virtual console by hitting alt-F1), or remote in as a non-sudoing user and then switch to root using `su` in a terminal.

Of course, Ubuntu doesn't let you log in as root by default, so this assumes you had previously changed that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restore some configuration files back to some previous state, you can always try to edit them, by booting your server with a Live version of some Ubuntu CD, mount the actual partition where the /etc files are located and edit them using vi.

You could also edit the file /etc/sudoers, in order to give more users the rights to become root.

Comment: The trick is to avoid rebooting the server ;). Thanks anyway.